# Azure Service Fabric - profiling standalone cluster apps

Tags: .net, profiling, azure-service-fabric

Is there any web monitoring system to remote profiling asp.net core applications, deployed to standalone local SF cluster? We've already tried to configure AppInsights Profiler, as discribed https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler but it seems to work with cloud deployed instance only. In addition, AppInsights is working itself for other purposes like query/fault monitoring, sql-query monitoring and others, except profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, indeed in cloud things with AI are kind of easier as all you need to do is to send data from WAD to Azure AI, which is achieved by adding an AI sink to the WAD configuration. But still you have options with a local environment as well -

1. Configuring AI with [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow)

Import the Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Output.ApplicationInsightsNuGet package, configure AI output with your key and you are good to go.

2. AI.SDK

The ApplicationInsight's Service Fabric NuGet package that includes specific stuff to get integrated with AI. Check out next articles - [ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric), [More telemetry from Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-more) and [Explore .NET trace logs in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs).

3. AI Listener and ETW

Here is the article that explains how to set up the Application Insights Listener that will send emitted events right into AI - [Distributed Tracing in Service Fabric using Application Insights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/10/06/distributed-tracing-in-service-fabric-using-application-insights/).

Comment: Thanks, we'll try to implement custom events as you adviced.